# How do webservers reliably determine the device that is sending requests?

Tags: javascript, webserver, browser-detection, mobile-browser

I've recently noticed that some websites that I visit are capable of detecting the device that I am using to view the website but I'm not sure how they are able to do that.

For example, www.rdio.com, a music streaming application, offers two different services; one for mobile devices and one for laptops and desktop computers. They charge $10/month for mobile devices and $5/month for desktops and laptops.

Obviously they must have a pretty good method for detecting the device that's sending requests as part of their business model depends on it. How do rdio and other companies achieve this? Everything I've thought of so far seems pretty bad. For example, if they depend on header variables in the http requests how do they guard against spoofing? Or if they use javascript on the client side to examine browser features, which features can you examine to accurately determine the device type? Do you look at screen resolution, or the presence of a gyroscope or something, because what if I have a mobile device with laptop style resolution, or a laptop with a gyroscope?

What features of the HTTP requests or the browsers do webservers examine in order to accurately determine the device type?

Comment: Have you signed up for the service? I sort of get the feeling that they may have a website plus a mobile app, although they don't seem to say that directly in any of their sales material.

Comment: Language like this could be a hint that there's a separate mobile app (emphasis mine): "Choose the music you want to play and listen as much as you want — from the web **or your phone, even when you’re offline**." Making a separation between "web" and "phone" may indicate the phone uses something other than a web browser (a native app). Plus the bit about listening offline, obviously.

Comment: @DaggNabbit I didn't think of the fact that they might have a separate mobile application. I don't have the service so I'm not sure about that.

Comment: just trying to think what I'd do in that position. You're right, none of the usual techniques are foolproof enough to prevent spoofing, and with a business model like that, I'd think you'd want to make sure you're not getting duped.

Comment: @DaggNabbit Even if they do have a separate mobile app, that wouldn't completely solve the issue. For example, I could still try to use the service on my mobile device using my mobile device's browser.

Comment: good point, but have you ever tried listening to e.g. soundcloud on a mobile browser? It sucks. I'd pay the extra few bucks for the app. That plus the usual browser detection should be enough, I'd think. Really no way to know what they're doing without signing up for it, though.

Comment: Last time I checked rdio had changed their pricing model to $10/month for web/browser and $12/month for web/browser/mobile/devices ... so it looks like even they've given up trying check the device. It's now a question of 'Did this request come via an app (which should have the ability to sign or hash requests) or via the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They depend upon the `User-Agent` of the browser to determine which kind of device the client is using.

Of course, User-Agents can be spoofed, and there isn't much that you can do to prevent it.

While there have been attempts to detect the real browser types by trying to invoke features that are specific to those browsers, this isn't reliable.

You can read more about [`User-Agent` here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

Comment: Actually, some of the web sites rely on the client (browser) to give them the browser capabilities (screen size, rendering engine, OS, etc.) and send it back to the server. This can be achieved in HTML/JS. Many web sites redirect you to a mobile version based on the first page.

Comment: How do you know this is the method rdio uses? You've just restated part of the OP ("if they depend on header variables in the http requests...") without addressing the specific question attached to it ("how do they guard against spoofing?").

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy `User-Agent` is also a browser supplied value.

Comment: @galuano1 yes it is, but all it provides is a string, that gets harder and harder to parse (look at a Chrome on Mac for example), and does not include resolution and screen depth info. Client side scripts can provide more information, and save you parsing and guessing.

Comment: @TravelingTechGuy Yes it does, and there are libraries which do all the parsing. You can get the screen size, but not the DPI from a browser. And pixel wise, there is not much difference between last years PC and this years smart phone. (Also, on PCs, browser may not be full screen, hence pixel may be lesser compared to phone.)

Comment: @galuano1 you still didn't answer his question. See my last comment. If they're using headers sent from the browser, how do they prevent spoofing? Also pretty much the whole second half of your previous comment is wildly inaccurate (hint: you'd check device width, not window width).

Comment: @galuano1 you are stating that they use the User-Agent header as if that is a fact. Do you have any proof? If not I'd suggest rewording it (they might do this, and they might take other measures as well, or they might do something entirely different, AFAIK).

Comment: I have the basic service that let's you use the Rdio web client on a desktop/laptop web browser and I tried to use that on an iPad. If you visit the site on an iPad, it'll redirect you to a page that asks you to download the rdio app. If you spoof the User-Agent then it'll send you to the normal desktop web client where you can do everything you'd normally be able to *except* play songs. You can queue up songs to play but they'll just remain paused.

Comment: @martega I wonder if it uses Flash to play the songs; maybe it works on Android? Also, ISTM that `User-Agent` is much less trouble to spoof than `screen.width`... You could add a check where things fail to work if the reported screen width is less than, say, 1280 px.